# RailsのDeviceで登録後に自動ログインさせたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails4.2を利用しております。

ログイン周りでDeviceのGemを利用していますが、ユーザーの登録時に自動的にログイン状態にしたいと思っております。（メール確認などは利用しておりません。）

シンプルな実装方法など教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すいません。そもそも前提が間違っておりました。
Deviseの標準の登録を使っていれば自動でsign_upされておりました。

今回、登録の処理を別フォームで行っていた為、sign_upメソッドもsign_inメソッドも呼び込まれませんでしたが、処理の最後にsign_in

```
@user = User.find_by_email("取得したメール")
sign_in @user
```

無事、自動ログイン出来ました。